# ?function does not show all arguments

Tags: r

I'm very new to R.

I noticed that some arguments are not specified in the help documentation. For e.g when I type in ?qplot (ggplot2) I cannot find the arguments for colour or shape anywhere except in the examples...

Am I missing something or are you meant to simply know all that fine-grind by yourself?

From R Help

```
Usage

qplot(x, y = NULL, ..., data, facets = NULL, margins = FALSE,
  geom = "auto", stat = list(NULL), position = list(NULL), xlim = c(NA,
  NA), ylim = c(NA, NA), log = "", main = NULL,
  xlab = deparse(substitute(x)), ylab = deparse(substitute(y)), asp = NA)
Arguments

x   
x values

y   
y values

... 
other aesthetics passed for each layer

data    
data frame to use (optional). If not specified, will create one, extracting vectors from the current environment.

facets  
faceting formula to use. Picks facet_wrap or facet_grid depending on whether the formula is one sided or two-sided

margins 
whether or not margins will be displayed

geom    
character vector specifying geom to use. Defaults to "point" if x and y are specified, and "histogram" if only x is specified.

stat    
character vector specifying statistics to use

position    
character vector giving position adjustment to use

xlim    
limits for x axis

ylim    
limits for y axis

log 
which variables to log transform ("x", "y", or "xy")

main    
character vector or expression for plot title

xlab    
character vector or expression for x axis label

ylab    
character vector or expression for y axis label

asp 
the y/x aspect ratio
```

Comment: That's the "..." part in the documentation which allows for "other aesthetics passed for each layer". R can pass though arguments to child functions.

Comment: "are you meant to simply know all that fine-grind by yourself?" For that package, yes. My understanding is that you need to learn the "grammar of graphics" before you'll know how to navigate its function arguments. Most alternatives for graphics (other R packages, Stata) are equally difficult, in my experience.

Comment: This also goes for standard R functions? I seem to recall that I couldn't find some arguments in the help documentation for some very basic functions.

Comment: `ggplot` can't really be learned by function documentation alone, but if you also look at the examples at the bottom it will help. Really, the thing to do is read some of the many many introductions to ggplot you can find on blogs and such around the web. Or even the [updated ggplot book](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2-book).

Comment: Yepp. Thank you. Is this the case for standard "build-in" R functions also? Or is the use-case and documentation there the same?

Comment: Yes and no. In general, all arguments should be documented, but take `?plot` for example. Due to S3 method dispatching, the actual arguments you need may be documented with the specific method, not at `?plot`, which can be confusing for beginners.

Comment: It's hard to say for all functions, but typically the "..." option is document and it tells you where the arguments are passed or it is described in the details section.

Comment: Mr Flick. May I ask, what do you mean with the "document"

Comment: I meant "documented", as in it's listed in the help page for that particular function.

Comment: The classic case of similar sources of confusion are the inter-dependencies of `plot.default`, `plot.window`, `par` and `axis`. And then there are the manifold variations on the meaning of "plot()". On my current console I get 110 items in a response to `methods(plot)`. You really do need to follow all of the "See Also" links in a help page, and then probably follow the "see Also" links in those pages as well. That said there an ongoing annoyance in the ggplot2 help pages from the many links to `?layer`. There is pretty much no reason to link to that page since it says basically nothing.